# How to pull data from one SQL Server database to other database server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, c#-4.0

I need your help in solving a database problem.

I have 5 tables (which are master table) in one of my database server and same 5 tables in my other database server (2nd server).

Now I want to create one scheduled job in SQL Server which pull data from source table to destination. For that I will write a stored procedure.

So what steps should I include in my stored procedure?

For example

1. Do I need to clean data from my destination table before inserting records from source?
2. How come I will know if source table row is updated?

Please help me with all the possible steps which I need to include and take care.

Answer (score 0):

There is a merge statement for this cases. You can read about it here [click!](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx)

Also you can do it in few steps:

-Update matching data using INNER JOIN

-Insert new data using LEFT JOIN